# How to find IFC Transformation for AxisPlacement..?

Tags: axis, transformation, coordinate-transformation, ifc, opencascade

i am trying to convert Ifc file to Step file format . for step files i need ifc transformation.

from the IfcClosedShell, i got face points but i need transform this points from IfcAxisPlacement3D (**cartesian Point , ref Direction , Axis Direction.**)

Matrix for transfer face Points to Original position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to parse the IFC and generate geometry? if you're not using anything beyond parsing the STEP file, be aware there are existing libraries out there to do the heavy lifting such as https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimEssentials

Comment: wow andy ward . thanks.. i had planned to get ifc objects details by own but this will save my lot of work and time.